# VSO Sort query results using tags

Tags: azure-devops

Has anyone found a workaround to allow them to Sort query results using tags in VSO?
The support page clearly states that Excel (as an export should be used). 
FYI: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/add-tags-to-work-items 
I was hoping someone found a way to sort based on tags where the result is:
- Tag #1
   - Feature
   - Feature
   - Feature
- Tag #2
   - Feature
   - Feature
   - Feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the query with the clause `Tags Contains tagname`. If you want to query more than one tag, you can continue add the same clauses with **OR** operation. Such as query tags `t1` and `t3` in the query, you can define as:

[image]

But the result can’t be ordered by Tags, Which I post an user voice [order query result by Tags](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19749202-order-query-result-by-tags) , you can vote and follow up.

Besides, you can also filter the WIT in Kanban board.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I added a vote to the linked feature request.